# Lumia imaging sdk 3 blur effect issue (The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50))

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, lumia-imaging-sdk

I need to render an xaml element and apply a blur effect using `LumiaImageSDK 3`

```
            var bitmapRended = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await bitmapRended.RenderAsync(LayoutRoot);

            IBuffer buffer = await bitmapRended.GetPixelsAsync();

            var target = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapRended.PixelWidth, bitmapRended.PixelHeight);
            var source = new BufferImageSource(buffer);
            var blur = new BlurEffect(source, 128);

            var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(blur, target);

            var result = await renderer.RenderAsync();

            var imgBrush = new ImageBrush();
            imgBrush.ImageSource = result;

            Menu.Background = imgBrush;
```

but when i run the code i get this error:

```
The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

i think is something related to the way i convert the  `RenderTargetBitmap` to an `IRandomAccessStream`.

the exception is raised from this line of code : `var result = await renderer.RenderAsync();`

it seams that the problem is a deadlock but i'm not able to find a solution

**edit: code updated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a IBuffer with the result (IBuffer buffer) then skip all the buffer manipulation and just create a BufferImageSource.

```
var target = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapRender.PixelWidth, bitmapRender.PixelHeight);
using (var source = new BufferImageSource(buffer))
using (var blur = new BlurEffect(source , 128))
using (var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(blur, target))
{
    var result = await renderer.RenderAsync();
}
```

That said I can't see an obvious problem with the code you wrote. I will have to look into it, but until then, have you made sure the stream is at the beginning? That is a common error with streams.

Comment: To my code i have added memStream.position = 0; but i still have the problem.
using your code i get an exception to this line var source = new BufferImageSource(buffer); 
the exception is: "No such interface supported"

Comment: this is the stack trace Lumia.Imaging.BufferImageSource..ctor(IBuffer buffer)
   at View.MainPage.<SetBlurredBackground>d__16.MoveNext()

Comment: What is in the buffer when you receive it?

Comment: the buffer is created from the rendered xaml element, the code is the first 3 row of my question

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue when using Lumia Imaging SDK. I am still checking the issue. However, to blur a image, using [Win2D](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D) is a alternative choice.

Your code above shows how to render a XAML UIElement as s stream or sth. Then you can blur it by using Win2D library. I have [post](http://juniperphoton.net/2015/09/30/apply-image-effect-using-win2d-2/) simply talking about how to do the blur stuff.

Hope it helps.

Comment: one problem with your solution is that i need touse a canvas to achive te result, instead i need to set the blurred image as a background of a stackpanel

Comment: Do the blur stuff as my post said and save it as an `Image` using `RenderTargetBitmap`  and set it as the background of your other StackPanel.